# Postgres select item from json in json_agg

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, lateral-join

```
with a as(
SELECT '[{"residential" : 100}, {"childcare" : 200}, {"open space" : 50}]'::jsonb t
)
select t->'childcare' from a
```

this keeps returning null when it should give me back 200.

same thing if I do `-->`

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data is an *array* of jsonb objects; you want to search the array for the object that has key `childcare`, and return the associated value.

For this, you would typically use a lateral join and `jsonb_array_elements`  to unnest the array, then filter the resulting objects with operator `?`.

So:

```sql
select x ->> 'childcare' childcare
from a
inner join lateral jsonb_array_elements(a.t) as x(elt) on x.elt ? 'childcare'
```

Note that `->>`  should be used instead of `->` in the `select` clause : the former gives you back a `text` value, while the latter returns `jsonb`.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/0-Itl4Kt)**